# Where is the best place to get resources(ex. drawable) with enum in Android

Tags: android, enums, architecture, resources

In case, there are resources to map to enum one by one, where is the best place to get resources?
Let me show you an example.

**Option 1** Place on enum value

```kotlin
enum class Job(@DrawableRes val drawableId: Int) {
    Doctor(R.drawable.doctor), Teacher(R.drawable.teacher)
}
```

This is simple, but I think it's not a good idea since the model should know Android specific class **R** and UI specific data directly.

**Option 2** Handle resources on enum class function

```kotlin
enum class Job {
    Doctor, Teacher;
    
    fun getDrawableId(): Int {
        when (this) {
            Doctor -> R.drawable.doctor
            Teacher -> R.drawable.teacher
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 3** Separate resources from enum class

```kotlin
enum class Job {
    Doctor, Teacher
}

class Something {
    fun getJobDrawableId(job: Job): Int {
        return when (job) {
            Doctor -> R.drawable.doctor
            Teacher -> R.drawable.teacher
        }
    }
}
```

If **Option 3** is best choice, what is the best for *Something*? Utility class, repository, Kotlin extension or something else?

**Option 4** The way beyond my head..

Comment: This belongs on softwareengineering stackexchange, not here.  But there's no real general answer to give you, because we don't know how this is going to be used.  Without that, we have no way of telling you what the right way to do it is.

Comment: One thing I will say is that you should probably look up sealed classes in kotlin, they might be more of what you're looking for than an enum.

Comment: I intended to separate domain layer(enum class) from Android framework and presentation layer. As you mentioned *sealed class*, I think adapter class may be useful in this case. Thanks.